# Facebook Graph API comments missing From (user who posted the comment)

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**Have you guys encounter this? Please let me know your thoughts!**

[image: Facebook Graph API comments]

The screenshot above is a response when I hit a get request to retrieve a comment from Facebook live. There are comments where the name of the user who made the comment does show up, but the majority of the comments don't have the name of the user.

Facebook documentation below shows field = from for the person that made the comment.
[Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v11.0/comment)

Comment: Facebook seems unable to fetch user post's comments through Facebook Graph API anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The [comments documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v11.0/comment) state that the field `from` return a `User` object and my suppose is that either you don't have the permission to read all the `User` objects or maybe that user has set some privacy restriction; unfortunatly as you saw, the Facebook API Doc is not complete and I did not find more info.